# How to change the value of an attribute of an online web page using C#

Tags: c#, bots

I am running this script to test my websites' login handling capabilites:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
string url = "mywebsites url";
wb.Url = new Uri(url);
wb.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", userName[0]);
```

Ive done a simmilar thing for the password and the submit. So the problem is that i get a warning saying NullReferenceException was unhandeled on this line:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", userName[0]);
```

despite having the url defined with the line above that one. Is there another reason other then the URL that i might have a nullreference error?

And how do i solve this? is there a better way of making a bot to test login capabilities of a web app?

Comment: I believe you are supposed to call wb.Navigate(new Uri(url)); before the Document property will be set.

Comment: If I understand correctly what it is you are trying to do, then something like Selenium might be very helpful.  Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334065/how-do-i-use-selenium-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a Null reference error on that line, then either:

`wb.Document.GetElementById("username")` is null (ie the element doesn't exist on the page)

or:

`userName[0]` is null (userName object is null or has no elements).

You should put in a breakpoint and inspect these things.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out i had an error with populating the array, which i didnt notice. I solved it nevertheless. Thank you for your answer.